# Mongo DB - Find between date range with format (dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss)

Tags: mongodb, date, format, find

I'm need to find documents between a date range, but the date field comes from the API as a String in the next format:

> 05-03-2020 16:04:17

I've tried doing this:

```
db.Collection.find({ date: { $gte: "2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",$lte: "2020-08-14T23:00:00.000Z" }});
```

and

```
db.Collection.find({ date: { $gte: "2019-12-01", $lte:"2020-08-14" }});
```

but does not match with any documents. I have to say that I cannot change the format of the date field.

Any idea how I can solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to change the date format also, in the db was saved as string and with mm/dd/yyyy format and this query helped me (using 11/22/2022 as example)

```
db.collection.find({
   "$expr":{
      "$and":[
         {
            "$gte":[
               {
                  "$dateFromString":{
                     "dateString":"$date",
                     "format":"%m/%d/%Y"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "$dateFromString":{
                     "dateString":"11/22/2022",
                     "format":"%m/%d/%Y"
                  }
               }
            ]
         },
         {
            "$lte":[
               {
                  "$dateFromString":{
                     "dateString":"$date",
                     "format":"%m/%d/%Y"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "$dateFromString":{
                     "dateString":"11/22/2022",
                     "format":"%m/%d/%Y"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the time strings in your application to time instances and query by time instances.

Comment: That would be the solution, but unfortunately I cannot change the format of the date field on the app, I am just building one of many modules.

Comment: Parse the time string in your module and query by time instance.

Answer (score 0):

if You Need Ans between Dates Then you need to try this.

```
db.Collection.find({ date: { $gte: new Date(Your Date in string),$lte: new Date( Your Date in string ) }});
```